# Devise confirmation email not converted from haml to html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm using Devise's confirmable module and when the app sends a email asking the user to confirm their email address, it doesn't convert the message form HAML to HTMl.  Instead, this is what gets delivered to the user.

```
%p Welcome #{@resource.email}! %p You can confirm your account 
email through the link   below: %p= link_to 'Confirm my account',
confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this documentation, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-custom-layouts

```
  config.to_prepare do
     Devise::Mailer.layout "email" # email.haml or email.erb
  end
```